Error Contact-fr In field: fullName - no CustomField named Contact.New_Field__c found
I have created new field in Contact object and added translation for French.
Ran validation(check-only) build via Jenkins on other org, it went successfully.
But when I am trying to deploy it on the same org, getting error like below:
Error Contact-fr In field: fullName - no CustomField named Contact.New_Field__c found
Is anyone is aware about this issue?

The issue is fixed when ran Jenkins build with DeployType parameter as Full instead of Delta:

